# Allowing others to change css of content inside iframe

Tags: css, http, iframe

I'm building a similar solution to twitter's widget.

I was wondering if there is any way to allow others to change the style of the content within my iframe?

I know the same-origin policy exists, however I wonder if there is any header notice that I could emit with the iframe content to allow browsers ignoring the policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about solution, when link to CSS file will be passed through URL parameter or (better solution in my opinion), create URL parameter for every customizable item like this?

```
?bgcolor=000000&fontcolor=ffffff
```

To your question about ignoring SOP, look at [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing):

- [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)
- [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Comment: I think a link to CSS file is the best solution for my problem. I was thinking about a data-style with some fancy json encoded css, but a link is much simpler.